# No puedo resolver un error en el constructor en Java

Tags: java

Tengo un problema con este método, me dice que hay un error en el constructor.

Este constructor lo tengo en una clase

```
 public Estudiante(int identificador, String nombre, String apellidos, String email, Sexo sexo, EstadoCivil estadoCivil, Calendar fechaNacimiento) {
    this.identificador = identificador;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellidos = apellidos;
    this.email = email;
    this.sexo = sexo;
    this.estadoCivil = estadoCivil;
    this.fechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento;
    this.fechaCreacion = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Y en otra clase tengo el siguiente que me da error:

```
                Calendar fecha =  new Estudiante().toCalendar(txtFecha.getText());
            Ventana.agregarEstudiante (new Estudiante(identificador, txtNombre.getText(),
                    txtApellidos.getText(), txtEmail.getText(), sexo, 
                    estadoCivil, fecha));
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "agregado!");                  
        }
```

Me da el siguiente error: `The constructor Estudiante() is undefined`

Comment: Cuando algo te da error, es conveniente que nos especifiques qué error. Sino es complicado. De todas formas, si tu constructor recibe parámetros, no puedes hacer `new Estudiante()` sin pasarle parámetros. Lee el mensaje del error y verás como te lo estará especificando claramente.

Comment: A que se refiere con introducir los parámetros?

Comment: Me refiero a esto: `Calendar fecha =  new Estudiante().toCalendar(txtFecha.getText());`. Estás creando un objeto Estudiante sin pasarle ningún parámetro y tu constructor está definido para recibir parámetros.

Comment: Realmente no entiendo qué sentido tiene esta línea en tu código: `Calendar fecha =  new Estudiante().toCalendar(txtFecha.getText());` ¿qué pinta el `new Estudiante` ahí cuando, según el constructor la fecha es un miembro de la clase `Estudiante`? ¿Lo que habría que hacer no es crear la fecha y pasarla al constructor de `Estudiante`?

Comment: Elimino esa linea?

Comment: Una pregunta porque tomas la fecha de "creación" o "nacimiento" para la fecha de **Calendar** según veo solo la presentas lo mismo en el constructor si quieres usar calendar era en la pantalla aqui solo pasas el valor no entiendo porque la sigues usas en el constructor y para pasarlo a la pantalla de **mensaje**

Comment: @MauricioContreras esto no tiene sentido: `Calendar fecha =  new Estudiante(<identificador>, <nombre>, <apellidos>, <email>, <sexo>, <estadoCivil>, <fechaNacimiento>)`, pues `Calendar` es una clase de Java, no puedes por tanto crear un objeto de ese tipo usando el constructor de `Persona`. Según lo que muestra el constructor de persona, y la lógica del código lo que habría que hacer es: 1. Crear un objeto de tipo `Calendar` y setearle la fecha que se recupera desde `txtFecha.getText()`; 2. Pasar ese objeto junto a los otros parámetros al constructor de `Persona`.

Comment: @ACedano, creo que tienes razón, no he leido bien la pregunta, sólo los comentarios, ese fue mi error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error que tienes es en la linea:

**Calendar fecha = new Estudiante().toCalendar(txtFecha.getText());**

Veras, al momento de crear tus propias clases en java, si tu no le defines un constructor, todas las clases java tienen el constructor por defecto el cual es:

**public ClassName( )**

Es decir, un constructor sin parametros.

Al momento que tu agregas uno a tu clase estudiante...

```
public Estudiante(int identificador, String nombre, String apellidos, String email, Sexo sexo, EstadoCivil estadoCivil, Calendar fechaNacimiento) { 
this.identificador = identificador;
 this.nombre = nombre; 
this.apellidos = apellidos;
 this.email = email; 
this.sexo = sexo; 
this.estadoCivil = estadoCivil; this.fechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento; 
this.fechaCreacion = Calendar.getInstance();
    }
```

Ese constructor por defecto (sin parametros) deja de estar definido automaticamente, por lo cual deberias agregarlo tambien, teniendo dos constructores en tu clase, uno sin parametros y otro con parametros.

Debido a que no lo has escrito, java te arroja ese error ya que no encuentra un contructor sin parametros por lo cual te dice que no esta definido.

Simplemente a tu clase estudiante agrega:

```
public Estudiante( ) {
}
```

Nota: observe que preguntaste que son los parametros, los parametros son las variables que tu le pasas al constructor entre los parentesis como:

```
int identificador

String nombre

String apellidos

String email

Sexo sexo

EstadoCivil estadoCivil

Calendar fechaNacimiento
```

Espero te ayude, suerte.

Comment: Yo definiría el constructor sin parámetros con valores por defecto para los atributos, como para no andar por la vida con valores nulos ;)

Comment: Hay muchas formas en las que puedes utilizar los constructores de tal forma que se adapten mejor a tus necesidades, cualquiera es correcta. Sin embargo, la pregunta surge de la necesidad de resolver el error que le es lanzado, no pregunta a cerca de como implementar su logica de programacion, por lo cual mencionarlo esta fuera del tema.

Comment: Las buenas prácticas siempre son on-topic. :)